# date issue due to datediff function in between

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, join

I have following query:

```
SELECT   
  datediff(d, 0, sauda_date),
  Scrip_Code,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty   ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyRate, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyAmount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellRate,
  (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) >
             SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) THEN 'BF' 
      ELSE 'BT' END ) as TradeType, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellAmount, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) - 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) as NETQTY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) - 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)as NetAmt,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) - 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) as PNLAmt 
FROM tradeFile 
where Inst_Type = 'FUTIDX' 
   OR Inst_Type='FUTSTK' 
  and Sauda_Date = convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') 
group by Scrip_Code, ExpiryDate, datediff(d,0,sauda_date)
```

**Result:**

[image]

This query is for taking sum of Buy_Qty,Sell_Qty datewise.[With ref to this quest:[not able to get individual date in query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168218/not-able-to-get-individual-date-in-query-result)

But as we can see datediff(d,0,sauda_date) column (i.e. first column) is giving me some result, but i wanted to add sauda_date also in this result as a date.

what changes i should make in this query.

I tried it by adding directly sauda_date in query but it gives me error.

Please guid me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `GROUP BY` in your query then (in case of T-SQL) in the field's part of a query you can use only fields from `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions (`SUM`, `COUNT`,....). So you can't add just `sauda_date`. You should add it with aggregate function. For example `MIN(sauda_date)`. OR you can add it to GROUP BY part.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure with your result requirement..

simply adding sauda_date in select list should not give error if you  includ it in group by list, i have tried belwo and its working.

```
Select datediff(d,0,f.Date), 
       sum(f.price), 
      f.OrderID,
       f.Date
from test f
group by f.Date,OrderID,datediff(d,0,f.Date)
```

Else
you can use self join to get only sauda date joining main result on your key column